# Using :checked selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm confused with the jquery checkbox :checked selector. Even after reading the documentation, I don't know how to use it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="addbox">
<h4><span class="addbox-text">Pick your best work from <b class="highlight-text">Flickr</b> to display in your portfolio</span></h4>
<div class="addbox-buttons"><input type="button" id="addbox-add" value="Add"><input type="button" id="addbox-cancel" value="Cancel"></div>
<div class="addmenu-item" id="addmenu-item-1e30"><span class="addmenu-image"><img class="addmenuimage" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7122/7424355198_72620895bd_m.jpg"></span><span class="addmenu-info"><input type="checkbox" id="add-check-1e30">Orchid Profiles</span></div>
<div class="addmenu-item" id="addmenu-item-1230"><span class="addmenu-image"><img class="addmenuimage" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7122/7424355198_72620895bd_m.jpg"></span><span class="addmenu-info"><input type="checkbox" id="add-check-1230">Orchid Profiles</span></div>
</div>​
```

**jQuery for checked**:

```
$("#addbox-add").click(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox] :checked").each( function() {
        alert("yes");
    });
});
```

There are two checkboxes if the add button is clicked it will show the alert message for each checked checkbox. But it is not working. Could anyone point out the mistake?

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd4uJ/1/)

Comment: See also: [What does a space in a jquery selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865910/what-does-a-space-in-a-jquery-selector-mean)

Comment: _"checkbox checked event."_ - Just a note about terminology: you mean the `:checked` _selector_.

Comment: @nnnnnn. +1, it tooks me a while to understand how those words related to the question... `:)`

Answer (score 6):

remove the space: **Working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/F6pag/4/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( function() {
//                     ^ ----- No space!!!
    alert("yes");
});
```

You had:

```
$("input[type=checkbox] :checked")
//                     ^--- Space! NO!!! :)
```

So your code searching for selected checkboxes\ radios inside checkboxes... Guess what, jQuery doesn't find any of those.

If there isn't a space, it's treated as extra filter info.

Just like:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").filter(':checked').each( function() {
    alert("yes");
});
```

By the way, **the later is faster.**

Comment: +1 but it might be helpful to point out what the space means, and what the incorrect selector actually tries to look for.

Comment: @tats, thanks for the DEMO, but watch out, you override my code... `:)` Thanks.

Comment: Well I use Mackbook Pro, and here in chrome its not working. Please once test it in Chrome.

Comment: @Subhajit. Working just fine.

Comment: don't know why its not working I am also not getting. please check on chrome once and let me know.

Comment: After checking the checkbox, we need to click on **Orchid Profiles** right? and then the alertbox should come?

Comment: @Subhajit. Yes, this is what your code does... you _can_ use the `change` event if you like to.