# jQuery - all children of a div with class of row

Tags: jquery, css

This may have been asked before but I am having troubles.  I am trying to do some jquery against all div.row within a div.panel-body.

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
  <div class=row>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying  something like this

```
$(".panel-body").children(".row").mouseover(function(){ $(this).addClass("mover");}).mouseout(function(){ $(this).removeClass("mover");})
```

If I use just `$(".row")` it works fine but it affects as you guess all elements with `class=row`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".panel-body .row")
```

This selects all descendants of `.panel-body` with a class of `.row`.

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865910/what-does-a-space-in-a-jquery-selector-mean) for more.  Or the [jQuery API.](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

**EDIT:
I made the assumption that you wanted *descendants* (meaning there may or may not be elements between `.panel-body` and `.row`, but you may only want *immediate* children.  In which case, you'll use @TeaCode's answer.**

Comment: Works great.  must have missed that in the documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child selector to filter the `.rows` divs. Like so.

```
$(".panel-body > .row")
  .mouseover( function() {  
  $(this).addClass("mover");})
  .mouseout( function() { 
  $(this).removeClass("mover");
})
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmbhfanx/) for sample.