# jQuery: is $('element img') the same as $('element').find('img');

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to optimize my jquery code and one of the things that I found is to use the find().

Is `$('element img')` the same as `$('element').find('img')`?

Comment: yes. it is same, having space in selector means child. using `.find()` is finding child

Comment: Are you asking if they have the same result (which they do), or if there are performance implications to using one or the other?

Comment: @nnnnnn Both, but if they are the same, then the find should be better performance wise according to jquery docs.

Comment: Seems like you've answered your own question then. Have you got a link to the relevant reference? (The [`.find()` page](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't mention performance.)

Comment: Yup, check this out: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: You can also do
var el = $('element');
var img = $('img', el);

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is: Yes

Optimizing jQuery reference: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in the jQuery selector are nothing but chained find equivalents. So, yes they are both identical.

Such as these 2:

```
$('div#post ul.tags li');
$('div#post').find('ul.tags').find('li');
```

However, because selction is from right to left, there cud be slight improvement in find in certain cases [Ref. jQuery Doc](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/):

```
// Fast:
$( "#container div.robotarm" );

// Super-fast:
$( "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );
```

Se this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865910/what-does-a-space-in-a-jquery-selector-mean)